# Obtención datos de formulario y mostrarlos en otra pagina

Tags: javascript, html

A ver si me podeis echar un cable. Estoy haciendo un formulario.

Lo hago todo con 3 archivos (index.html, action.html y gestion.js):
-En el archivo "index.html" tengo el formulario con sus campos y el botoón "enviar datos". Tengo una referencia a un javascript donde voy a gestionar el botón "Enviar datos". En la etiqueta  tengo el atributo "action" donde pongo el archivo "action.html" para que salte esa página nada más pulsar el botón "enviar datos".
-En "enviado.html" no tengo nada. Sólo lo que pone por defecto (doctype, html, head,body).
-En "gestion.js" tengo que, mediante métodos de DOM, nos escriba los datos en una línea distinta cada uno.

Todo esto está bien. Doy al botón "enviar datos", el formulario  desaparece y aparecen los datos uno a uno, linea a linea. Peeeeero, miro la url y me los está mostrando en "index.html", no en "action.html", que es lo que yo pretendo.

El caso es que, en el javascript, para que funcione, empiezo con window.onload y luego pongo la función. Haciéndolo así, todo  sale bien pero me queda todo en la página "index.html". Si quito window.onload, me abre "action.html" pero no me muestra los datos.

Espero que me podais ayudar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: con JavaScript y html únicamente no es posible hacer lo que quieres. Necesitas algo en el back, in servidor como Apache o node, o flask, ... Qué gestione los datos que me llegan del formulario para mostrarlos en otro archivo, o guardalos.

Comment: Hola, quizá para mejorar la ayuda que te podamos dar, sería bueno que coloques el código, y no imágenes. Pero basicamente creo que se puede solucionar agregando un onclick en el submit, algo asi: onclick="window.location.href = 'enviado.html';" y en el form puedes usar target="_blank"

Comment: Bienvenido @user158414. Tu pregunta parece tener buena pinta, sin embargo, va a ser muy difícil poder ayudarte si dejas las imágenes en lugar del código para copiarlo y probarlo. Considere reemplazar las imágenes por el código. Por otro lado, te invito a [realizar un recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que ganes tu primera medalla y consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Si presentas algún problema para colocar tu código acá, puedes consultar [Ayuda de edición de Markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Te ayudará mucho.

Comment: Pero cuando cambies de una pagina a otra, todo lo recolectado de los inputs del formulario se perderá y no va a ser posible renderizarlo en "enviado.html", ya que el dom del primer html no es el mismo dom que el del segunto, para eso deberias hacer uso de algun lenguaje como php para enviar datos al servidor, Tambien podrias hacerlo con las variables de localStorage, pero solo serviria para que lo veas vos, y cuando cierres el navegador o limpies vacies caché se perderan todos los datos

Answer (score 1):

Usa localStorage para retener la información en lugar de enviarla de un formulario a otro, por ejemplo en Pagina1.html el html podria ser

```
<input type="text" id="item-1">
<input type="text" id="item-2">
<input type="text" id="item-3">
<input type="text" id="item-4">

<span id="enviar">Enviar</span>
```

Y en javascript almacenas los datos y envias a la pagina2.html

```
const Inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let form = [...Inputs].map(item => {
    return {id:item.id, value:item.value};
  });
    window.localStorage.setItem('form', JSON.stringify(form));
  window.location.href = 'pagina2.html';
});
```

Con esto ya tienes los datos almacenados y no importa a que pagina de tu sitio vayas, siempre puedes recuperarlos con

```
let form2 = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('form'));
```